# PWM Not Driving IRL520N MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, pwm, mosfet-driver

I am trying to switch a [IRL520N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irl520npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565f9b62255b) logic-level MOSFET using a 0-5V PWM signal from my microcontroller (PyCom FiPy).

I tested just the MOSFET with a 10 Ohm series gate resistor and my load is a 9-15V brushless DC pump ([TD-3LS from this manufacturer](http://209.114.199.11/page.asp?p=pump_TD-3)). I had my load rail at +12V and a power supply driving the gate at around 2.3V-4V. The pump ran just fine.

Then I hooked it up to a function generator to test the PWM signal at the gate. I tested a variety of amplitudes (0-5V, 0-10V), frequencies (500mHz to 5kHz), and duty cycles (0-100%). None of them turned on the MOSFET and ran the pump.

I've attached a schematic of the final pump drive circuit that this MOSFET will be going into and the original designer said that he got it to work with a PWM signal of 5V, 2.4kHz, and 0-100%, so I'm not sure why I can't even get the MOSFET to work on it's own (note: I've also tested this circuit with a variety of PWM signals and steady drive voltages, and could not get it to switch on the pump).

C35: [UFW1H470MED1TD](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/nichicon/UFW1H470MED1TD/493-11014-1-ND/4317921)
L2: [1536Y](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/71?k=inductor&k=&pkeyword=inductor&sv=0&s=8406&pv1989=0&pv2087=u500%C2%B5H&sf=0&FV=ffe00047&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&datasheet=1&rohs=1&pageSize=25)
Pump DCR: 9kOhm

[image: Pump Drive Circuit]

EDIT: I was able to get the pump running off the IRL520N MOSFET. It needs to run for a few seconds at 100% duty cycle first before switching to a pulse (duty cycle was 50-75% at a frequency of 500 Hz from the Arduino). However, still not able to get it running with the driver circuit below, so open to any suggestions about what could be wrong with that. I thought maybe I wasn't giving enough time for the capacitor to charge up so I ran the pump at 100% duty for 20s before switching to the PWM, but still nothing.

Comment: Your schematic has several mistakes that would stop it cold. Where did you get this from?

Comment: I'm adapting an existing design. This circuit has been built and tested by the original designer and it worked for him. But regardless of this circuit, I can't even get the MOSFET on it's own to run on PWM.

Comment: Repeat 1st test "12V and a power supply driving the gate at around 2.3V-4V."  if that works then you have a schematic and/or wiring errors. If it fails congratulations on your 1st ESD failures

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 thank you for your comments but that does not address the PWM issue. Please disregard the schematic for now. I care first about getting the MOSFET alone to work. As mentioned, it works with a constant drive voltage, but NOT with PWM. I hasn't been destroyed by ESD (yet) because I alternate between testing constant voltage and PWM and it works with the constant voltage and not with the PWM.

As for the schematic, I do not see what is wrong with it but I'd be grateful if you pointed out any errors. I tested the very simple two-layer board for wiring continuity and it is fine.

Comment: The pump seems to be a two wire brushless pump which would have it's own breaker inside ...ie you apply 12V and it pumps. This is unsuitable for a PWM drive unless it was at very very low frame rates ….perhaps only 5-10Hz or less.

Comment: Motors tend to have a start surge current 10x the average due to the V+/DCR ratio being 10x . If your Capacitive load is not resonant to match the LC resonance, you can be driving a very low impedance of either coil DCR if too slow or ESR of Cap if too fast.  Dissipation factor of 1% cap is a 100:1 ratio ( reactance/ESR) at 120 Hz.  SO an exact schematic and pump impedance must be defined to analyze correctly.

Comment: A  relaxation oscillator can be voltage controlled with DC to affect the frequency of the pump but to do with PWM requires a deeper understanding of switched Z(f) and peak/rms I ratio which requires knowing the spectral content of the PWM and resonant frequency impedance changes  Then you will find noises that relate to aliasing issues.  i.e. try a better design that works like a simple adjustable linear regulator or a sensor feedback approach.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 This is NOT a motor driven pump, but more like a solenoid driving a diaphragm, so that was just whole bunch of crap you described. This type of pump was very common as a fuel pump (for a carburetor) many years ago. They sound as if they at ticking when running. Where do you come up with this stuff??

Comment: You misunderstand @JackCreasey and your derogatory comments reflect badly on you and show flawed fundamentals of solenoid pumps with  hysteretic switches. It is a linear solenoid motor until displacement switch cuts off current then a spring relaxation time. So the current is a decaying pulse of some duty cycle resulting and Pk/RMS ratio >>1 with a pump cycle time or 1/frequency that is dependent on Vdc. I understand perfectly. You however, I wonder . A rotary motor pulses with surge current the same on startup. due to L/DCR=T time constant ratio and V/DCR current peak

Comment: Jack your misunderstanding is flawed .  Only the start pulse of a rotary motor is similar to a start pulse of solenoid until cutoff.  Hence your "tick" sound  is my pulsed current Pk/RMS which repeats at the relaxation cycle rate or resonant frequency of the spring and MMF force time

Comment: Jack Therefore my comments remain valid and your comments are not.

Comment: Hi folks. Thank you for interest @SunnyskyguyEE75 but I feel that your comments are over my head and not helping me to understand what's going on with the MOSFET.

Comment: @JackCreasey I can perhaps understand that the pump itself would not respond favorably to a PWM, but why not the MOSFET? And why not the MOSFET with the above driver circuit (with the cap & inductor to smooth out the transients and apply a constant voltage reflective of the duty cycle)?

Comment: @YNGVV  If you want a good answer, pls fix your question with the correct schematic and more details.  The answer can be explained by in the source/ load impedance ratio as a function of spectral content in simple terms but without details we can only guess you have the wrong parts.

Comment: Here I used the RdsOn and LC parts in your schematic but I had to guess on pump inductance.  Your filter suggests  1kHz PWM may work BUT only 150mOhms RdsON is much less than the DCR of the pump. ( measure with DMM) https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sr4E.png  But if cannot turn on the Pump then the L/DCR of the pump is too great or the Vgs is too low or you cannot get Vbat to the load due to overload. (Ipk/Irms) where Irms = 70 ma no load @ 12.5V and I estimate Ipk 10x or 700mA which if battery is good, should work if your RdsOn is 150 mOhm at 1kHz rate. What is your Cap ESR? pump DCR? battery ESR?

Comment: The problem really is about impedances being too high and thus not enough current to start pump.

Comment: Hi @SunnyskyguyEE75 I don't know how I can make my schematic more clear or my question more detailed, given that I have provided all relevant part numbers and datasheets. You have yet to tell me what is wrong with the schematic. The cap I'm using is UFW1H470MED1TD (unknown ESR) and the inductor is 1536Y. Right now I'm not using a battery on VBAT but rather a power supply. The DCR of my pump appears to be 9kOhm on a multimeter.

Comment: It really doesn't sound like your pump is designed to support PWM drive; most things with internal electronic commutation fundamentally are not, especially as starting a brushless motor is fairly complex control task.  Some small fans might be a possible exception (or are just frequently *abused*), but even there the ones really intended for this have a PWM input pin, you do not PWM their supply.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, thanks for the note. Please see my edit above where I was able to get the pump to run on PWM through the MOSFET (just need that steady starting voltage). It's the only way we can reliably adjust the source voltage (and thus, the flow rate) since it will be powered by a battery. The original designer got it to work reliably and I'm trying to replicate that.

Comment: My guess is the inductor DCR is too high and the PWM raises the impedance just enough so the pump cannot start.  In future you must include part numbers for every part with datasheets and model your logic diagram which is OK for conceptual understanding to a real model with actual DCR, ESR of every part.  inductive load and commutation rate.  something like this but even more https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sr4E.png

Comment: My Rule of thumb is your inductor must have a DCR  less than the MOSFET of 150mohm or in other words Imax > 20 the rated switched inductive current and >=20x for MOSFET current ratio to load. I was asking for a real model , but a logic diagram and parts list with datasheet links would do for every part. and for relaxation pump motor you must measure DCR and L with expected frequency range of pump current spikes. The latter changes with air pressure.

Comment: @YNGVV - your description confirms why this is the wrong way to do things.  Just because someone else got away with a fundamentally broken idea does not mean you will.  **Your device is not designed for PWM usage, period**.  If you want to try to modulate its effort upstream of the internal electronics, you need a switch-mode *voltage regulator* not a crude PWM which keeps pulling the plug on the commutation algorithm.  The proper solution however would be something where the brushless communication driver had a *control input*.